# Unity returning null after serializing JSON to object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I am using the object:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UserData
{
    [JsonProperty("uid")] public int UID;
    [JsonProperty("email")] public string Email;
    [JsonProperty("password")] public string Password;
}
```

And converting it using:

```
UserData parsedUserData = JsonUtility.FromJson<UserData>(stringUserData);
```

But then the `parsedUserData.UID` is `0`, the `Email` and `Password` are `null`

It worked before and I don't know what changed.

I checked and the string is fine but after parsing it's null

The JSON:

```
{"uid":1,"email":"user1","password":"password"}
```

Comment: Pls post your json string pls. Nobody can help you without this

Comment: @Serge Added it, I don't really need a solution, just figured it out.
I also posted the problem I had and solution. thanks

Comment: `I don't really need a solution` .. why post a question then? ^^

Comment: First of all, I needed one when I posted the question,. Second of all, there is no solution for this problem online so it's for the next person to have this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem,
`JsonUtility.FromJson` does not work with `JsonProperty`

To fix this all I had to do it to use `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

And replace `JsonUtility.FromJson` to the .net option `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

The final code is:

```
UserData parsedUserData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(stringUserData);
```

Hopes this help anyone else with this problem.

Comment: How long it took to find the answer? Or you  prepared the answer before you had posted the question?

Comment: Like 2 hours, my submitting the post probably took a while because of my internet speed.
Anyway I don't see why is that a problem?

Comment: The problem is that you had 2 hours and could not even test  your answer. Your code is still is not working properly since you have to fix the class too. Just for the future, pls don't post questions and bad answers together. It is not Q&A helper here. There are a lot of users who desperately need some help and  can't find the answer

Comment: I don't need to fix the class, this works as is for me. (After another look at the question, the Json I posted was the wrong one. Because the question was simplified, my full class is way too big and not relevant to the question.)

Comment: @Serge, it's a valid problem. His code was fine, the issue is with the package he was using. This is a question I myself have had and struggled with a long time ago. `JsonUtility` is a horrible library that is used in official documentation. He had an honest problem with a library that didn't work correctly. He probably looked at the documentation and it still didn't work. So he posted a question. Then decided to use a different library because he kept searching.

Comment: @CorrieJanse Did you read my comment? amitklein answer is not correct,  I am not even talking that there are many answers at SO that advise to use Newtonsoft. Json and they contain correct code.

Comment: @CorrieJanse if you check activities on the post, you will see that  only after my comment    amitclein has changed the json string

Comment: @Serge, yes, thanks you for noticing that. just take notice that the JSON itself is not really a part of this problem because as I said in the question, it worked for me and the code itself changed.

Comment: In Unity's `JsonUtility` the field names have to match **exatcly** the json field names as it uses the same serializer for everything. There is no attribute in Unity to modify this or remap fields (except maybe even `[FormerSerializedAs]`). period. If you rather want to use Newtonsoft this is of course up to you but I would not claim it is **the** answer for your question ;) .. Your Json has to match the fieldnames.

Comment: Well, I did say that you can remove it and that this was the problem.. I just added that I did to not have that problem anymore